# generate JSON file during Webpack build

Tags: javascript, ajax, webpack, webpack-3

I'm using Webpack to build my assets for Chrome Extension.
Usually in the `/dist` you should have some JS files, some HTML files, **and `manifest.json`**

Previously I had this file created somewhere and using `'copy-webpack-plugin'` I simply copied that to the `/dist` folder,
 like this:

[image]

But now, I need to generate this `manifest.json` dynamically. I need to make AJAX request, get some data needed in the `manifest.json`, generate this file, and then put it in the `/dist` folder.

I'm familiar with Node.js and I know how to get AJAX data. I may be able to google how to generate JSON file. But how can I connect this Node.js app with Webpack build I have no idea. Should I use a plugin?

Please help me with this. I'm using `"webpack": "^3.0.0",`

Comment: copy-webpack-plugin has a transform attribute, you can use that to write whatever you want in this file https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#transform

Comment: @lukas-reineke yes, that helped, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I managed to implement this using `transform` method:

[image]